# zsh: exec format error: cardano-node on MacOS BigSur

Tags: cardano-node, macos

> I'm getting this `zsh: exec format error: cardano-node`
> I ran `file $(command -v cardano-node)`
> This returned the following
> `/usr/local/bin/cardano-node: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped`
> this looks to be correct. So why am I getting "exec format error"
> Any help de-bugging would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile it on that architecture and version of MacOS?

Can only check for you against version 1.33 compiled on Ubuntu which reports a few of differences which might point to the way you compiled?

```
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=b832d0d517ddc9b6e4d692d4cb2fb6663136e8ae, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm running this on MacOs BigSur I have an intel i7 processor on the mac. So it is 64 bit is there something else I need to check?  I did the Brew install  with cardano-node version 1.33.0

Answer (score 0):

Did you install an already build binary or did you build the binary from source? The M1 processors also tend to have slight differences.

For mac I would recommend building your own binaries. This is probably the safest besides also checking a checksum or hash of the already built binaries.

Here's an instructional link on how to build cardano-node and cardano-cli from source:
[Building from source on MacOS](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node/#macos)

Comment: Thank you for the response as it turned out my server instance did not have enough RAM, after upgrading to 16 GB my issues where resolved.